# Are questions about boardgames-related events on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm talking about events like SPIEL in Essen, where many new games are shown to the public at 1st time. Mostly these questions would be not about specific game, but still related to boardgames. And I can't imagine other stackexchange site, which would be more related to this.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Definitely on-topic.

Comment: I agree with this, but does that mean "when is X game (expansion) being released" on-topic as well?.

Comment: @Egg: This kind of question should be closed as Too Localized. They have expiration date. A precise answer is hard.